# Batch processing using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, batch

I am using ArcMap 10.4.1.

I have 150 LiDAR files which I all need to rename since they have a "-" in their name and also need to assign a projection to them. I actually don´t know how to rename them all in a batch.
For the projection I have been trying to run the Define Projection tool in a Batch. The tool works, but the layers still don´t have a projection assigned afterwards.

Don´t really understand the problem.

Comment: Edit your question - When you say "lidar files" what format are they? Saying a tool did not work is unhelpful, you don't say what the error message is and how you set up the tool. Improve your question. Include images and for the record batch processing is definitely possible in modelbuilder.

Comment: Consider writing a python script to do the batch renaming. It could also do the batch projecting.